# Flutter: How to jump to initial page without dynamic button click event after PageView build

Tags: flutter

I need to automatically jump to 2nd page after pageview build.

I already tried:

```
_pageController = PageController(initialPage: 1, keepPage: false);
_pageController.jumpToPage(1); //removed this line cause of errors
```

Code

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return SizedBox(
    height: _pageViewHeight,
    child: PageView.builder(
      physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
      itemCount: state.accountList.length,
      controller: _pageController,
      onPageChanged: (int pageIndex) {
      },

      // Body
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int itemIndex) {
        return _buildPageViewItem(context, state.accountList[itemIndex]);
      },
    ),
  );
}
```

Following errors occured:

```
ScrollController not attached to any scroll views.
'package:flutter/src/widgets/scroll_controller.dart':
Failed assertion: line 110 pos 12: '_positions.isNotEmpty'
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: ScrollController.position
Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart': 
Failed assertion: line 263 pos 16: 'child == null || indexOf(child) > index': is not true.
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It's good that you have a call stack, but we may only need the first and last bits of the error message. Also, you can put this information inside code blocks with 3 backticks.

Comment: remove `_pageController.jumpToPage(1);`

Comment: @pskink yes. i removed that line. but how to jump 2nd page without jumpToPage function.

Comment: use `initialPage` in the [constructor](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PageController/PageController.html)